# Onleftclick & onrightClick Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events

In my server side code I am dynamically building a table and and right now I am adding the following code to handle the row click.

```
tr.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('" + root + document.IPT_Name + "/" + document.IPT_Sub_Name + "/" + document.File_Name + "', 'mywindow', 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no, resizable=yes')");
```

Is there any way to make this work only a left click and then add a different attribute to the right click to go to a different location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect it, but there are some browser specific issues you have to watch. Here is some code from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

```
function doSomething(e) {
  var rightclick;
  if (!e) var e = window.event;
  if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
  else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);
  alert('Rightclick: ' + rightclick); // true or false
}
```

There's also a plug-in for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) that lets you detect right mouse clicks: http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook/68

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code taken out of [jQuery 1.3.2](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js) with comments that explain about `event.which` and `event.button`.

```
// Add which for click: 1 == left; 2 == middle; 3 == right
// Note: button is not normalized, so don't use it
if ( !event.which && event.button )
    event.which = (event.button & 1 ? 1 : ( event.button & 2 ? 3 : ( event.button & 4 ? 2 : 0 ) ));
```